# using jquery to dynamically change webkit

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, webkit

i am trying how to use jquery to dynamically change -webkit.

my css

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    height: 75px;
    width: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

my jquery

```
        $('::-webkit-scrollbar-button').css("height",'100px');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just dynamically add a script element.

```
$('body').append('<style>::-webkit-scrollbar-button{height:75px;}</style>');
```

If you have to change this frequently you can remove the last one before you add the next one, but it wouldn't exactly be *necessary* because the last one would take precedence.

```
var $style = $('<style id="dynamicStyle">::-webkit-scrollbar-button{height:75px;}</style>');
$('#dynamicStyle').remove();
$('body').append($style);
```